# I would like to ask about AVL tree of C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

Today, I submitted an assignment on C++ AVL trees for a data structures class at university, and I was punched for only looking at the class part, saying that I couldn't do this basic stuff, and what have I been learning all this time? What was wrong with it?

He said about something like 'private' and 'public', but I couldn't understand it.

```
using namespace std;
template<typename Key, typename Info>
class Dictionary{
    /* node */
    struct node_t{
        Key key;
        Info info;
        node_t *left;
        node_t *right;
        node_t(Key KEY,Info INFO, node_t* LEFT, node_t* RIGHT) : key(KEY), info(INFO), left(LEFT), right(RIGHT) { }
    };
    node_t* root;
public:
    Dictionary(){
        root = nullptr;
    }
    ~Dictionary(){
        deleteTree();
    }
    int getHeight(node_t *node);
    node_t *leftRotate(node_t *root,node_t *node,node_t *parent, int direction);
    node_t *rightRotate(node_t *root,node_t *node,node_t *parent, int direction);
    node_t *rightLeftRotate(node_t *root,node_t *node,node_t *parent, int direction);
    node_t *leftRightRotate(node_t *root,node_t *node,node_t *parent, int direction);
    node_t *balancing(node_t *root, node_t *node, node_t *parent, int direction, int 
    *branch, int num_branch);
    node_t *deleteNoChildNode(node_t *root, node_t *node, node_t *parent);
    node_t *deleteOneChildNode(node_t *root, node_t *node, node_t * child);
    node_t *deleteTwoChildNode(node_t *root, node_t *node, int *branch, int *num_branch);
    node_t *deleteNodeByKey(Key key);
    bool searchNode(Key key);
    void deleteNodeRecursively(node_t *root);
    void deleteTree();
    bool addNode(Key key, Info info);
    void printTree();
    void printNode(node_t *root, int depth);
};


using namespace std;
template<typename Key, typename Info>
class Dictionary{
    /* node */
    struct node_t{
        Key key;
        Info info;
        node_t *left;
        node_t *right;
        node_t(Key KEY,Info INFO, node_t* LEFT, node_t* RIGHT) : key(KEY), info(INFO), left(LEFT), right(RIGHT) { }
    };
    node_t* root;
public:
    Dictionary(){
        root = nullptr;
    }
    ~Dictionary(){
        deleteTree();
    }
    int getHeight(node_t *node);
    node_t *leftRotate(node_t *root,node_t *node,node_t *parent, int direction);
    node_t *rightRotate(node_t *root,node_t *node,node_t *parent, int direction);
    node_t *rightLeftRotate(node_t *root,node_t *node,node_t *parent, int direction);
    node_t *leftRightRotate(node_t *root,node_t *node,node_t *parent, int direction);
    node_t *balancing(node_t *root, node_t *node, node_t *parent, int direction, int *branch, int num_branch);
    node_t *deleteNoChildNode(node_t *root, node_t *node, node_t *parent);
    node_t *deleteOneChildNode(node_t *root, node_t *node, node_t * child);
    node_t *deleteTwoChildNode(node_t *root, node_t *node, int *branch, int *num_branch);
    node_t *deleteNodeByKey(Key key);
    bool searchNode(Key key);
    void deleteNodeRecursively(node_t *root);
    void deleteTree();
    bool addNode(Key key, Info info);
    void printTree();
    void printNode(node_t *root, int depth);
};
```

Comment: Would you want to allow a user of your `Dictionary` to rotate arbitrarily any nodes? This functionally is internal and should only be accessible from internally, thus the those functions – among others – should be private!

Comment: some of the functions should private like ```leftRotate```  may be that's why teacher was not happy

Comment: The functions that are valid (but I'd prefer better naming) as public interface are adding and searching for nodes (`add` or `insert`, `contains`) and deleting everything (`clear`). You yet need a way to retrieve the info for a specific key, iterate over all nodes contained, and you should leave printing to the user – not every one would like to print the tree the same way, by allowing to iterate you give every one the possibility to do the way whichever she/he wants to.